# Ansible Runtime error when executing play to calculate total file size across more than one destination hosts

Tags: ansible, runtime-error, filesize, cumulative-sum, ansible-inventory

I'm looking to calculate the sum of filesizes of a set of files `source_file_new` across a set of hosts `destnode`

```
- name: "Play 1"
  hosts: "destnode"
  tasks:
    - name: Check all filesizes across all hosts
      include_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/checkfilesize.yml"
      with_items:
        - "{{ source_file_new.splitlines() }}"


- name: "Play 2"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Set overall size as fact for all files across all destnodes
      set_fact:
        overall_size: "{{ groups['destnode'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'totalsize') | map('int') | sum }}"

    - name: Fail download if the source is more than 15GB
      fail:
        msg: "Download failed because the total file size you are trying to download across all hosts are more than 15GB and out of capacity for our Dump Server"
      when: overall_size | int > 15000
```

cat checkfilesize.yml

```
- name: Check file size
  raw: "du -sk {{ item }} | awk '{ print $1 }'"
  register: file_size

- set_fact:
    totalsize: "{{ totalsize | default(0) |int + ( file_size.stdout | int / 1024 ) | int }}"

- debug:
    msg: "TOTALSIZE: {{ totalsize }}"
```

Runs as:

```
ansible-playbook -i my.hosts getfiles.yml -e source_file_new="/tmp/file1,/tmp/file2"
```

This works perfectly fine when `destnode` is a single host entry

cat my.hosts

```
[destnode]
myhost7
```

However, when `destnode` is multiple hosts the run fails with the below error:

cat my.hosts

```
[destnode]
myhost5
myhost7
myhost9
```

Runtime error when `multiple destnode` entries:

```
TASK [Set overall size as fact for all destnodes] **********************************
task path: /web/playbooks/automation/getfiles/getfiles.yml:65
Tuesday 08 November 2022  04:32:50 -0600 (0:00:00.927)       0:00:07.025 ****** 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'totalsize'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/web/playbooks/automation/getfiles/getfiles.yml': line 65, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Set overall size as fact for all hosts\n      ^ here\n"}
```

I have made sure that `/tmp/file1,/tmp/file2` exists across all hosts `destnode`

So, if `/tmp/file1` is 3GB and `/tmp/file2` is 3GB then it is not fail when single `destnode` and fail when multiple `3hosts X 2files X 3GB = 18GB` i.e greater than 15GB.

Can you please suggest what could be wrong?

Comment: You haven't shown us where you're setting `totalsize`. Presumably that's somewhere in `checkfilesize.yml`; please include that playbook in your question.

Comment: @larsks extremely sorry as i missed it. Now ... i have updated the same in the original post.

Comment: The task you show in your error output ("Set overall size as fact for all hosts") doesn't match the task name in your example playbook. Are you certain the code you've posted produces the error you're asking about? Using your playbooks I am unable to reproduce this error using a small inventory with three hosts.

Comment: @larsks the output task prints `Set overall size as fact for all destnodes` and matches the yml task. for simplicity i had manually changed it but have corrected the original post.

Comment: @larsks my bad ... the error was coming due to one of the hosts not reachable.